# php created ics File not showing time in Outlook

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I created an ics file with php. My Code gives me this file. If I open this with Google Calendar, everything is fine. But opening with Outlook, it doesnt show the time.

Any hints?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:company
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Buchung_32232
DTSTAMP:20220324T143023
SEQUENCE:1
CREATED:20220324T143023
LAST-MODIFIED:20220324T143023
DTSTART:20220324T180000
DTEND:20220324T230000
SUMMARY:Buchung
DESCRIPTION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: According to [this validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html), you are missing a `PRODID`

Comment: doesn't work either unfortunatly

Comment: I have tested - it works (both start time and end time are correctly displayed) when the ics is opened in Outlook . See the result [here](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/soresult2_24March2022.jpg) - So your problem is un-reproducible. I strongly recommend you to open the same ics file in another computer with outlook installed and see the effect.